# Помогите сделать Linq запрос

Tags: c#, linq

И так, этот код выводит 60 80 (пропадает единица), как сделать чтобы linq запрос возвращал 1 60 80, то есть элементы большие 5 умножал на 10, но меньшие 5 оставались на своих местах. Ну и разумеется при других значениях в numbers программа должна работать похожим образом, например { 2, 7, 3, 9 } -> 2 70 3 90. Вот.

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int[] { 1, 6, 8 };

numbers = numbers.Where(i => i > 5).Select(i => i * 10);

foreach (int number in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers = numbers.Select(i => i < 5? i : i * 10);`